# Google Web Toolkit in eclipse randomly requires me to reset GWT SDK

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I downloaded and install the latest version of Google App Engine Plugin into my Eclipse and created a project with it using both GAE SDK and GWT SDK.
The funny thing is, randomly, my project become subjective to error, like the class RemoteServiceServlet cannot be resolved.
The errors will be removed if I go to the configure tab of the project and change the GWT SDK from `Default` to `Specific version` (or vice versa).

Has anyone ever encountered the same error? What the heck is it?

Comment: I did encounter the same problem.

Comment: I have also encountered this problem previously. I have observed it on Linux (Ubuntu), Mac OSX and Windows 7 machines, though I have not tracked down a real solution to it yet because, as you described above, changing the GWT SDK from default to specific seems to reset whatever went wrong...